# Silent install msi applications with arguments using PowerShell

Tags: installation, msi

I am fairly new to powershell scripting.

I need to silently install an msi file using PowerShell with dynamic property. 
I am able to edit the location where the file will be installed.

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\myAdmin\Desktop\sample\myMSI.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\myfolder /quiet'
```

What I need to do now is change the selected `RadioButton` that has been selected from the default value of "Connectivity Only" to "Client & administrator". I got the property of the radio button using `superOrca`.

[image]
I am having problem when I add the InstallMode to the arguement as it does not reflect in the installation

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\myAdmin\Desktop\sample\myMSI.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\myfolder InstallMode=1000 /quiet'
```

Any ideas how to change the selected `radiobutton`?

Comment: You can only change a property from the command line if the property is public (name is in all caps). If the property is not public then I would suggest creating a transform to deploy with the install that changes the value. Regardless, this is not a powershell question.